# How to get guild id and all channel's id in that guild

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I was trying to make my bot to get server and guild id on join and save it into a database but some things were not clear for me, and so I'm asking some questions.

Below is the initial code that I wrote to acheive my goal I said:

```
@Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
    db.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO war_guild (GuildID) VALUES (?)', self.guild.id)
    self.guild = self.get_guild(db.record('SELECT GuildID FROM war_guild', *))
    existing_text_channel = [(GuildChannel.name, GuildChannel.id) for '(#text channels)' in self.guild]
    existing_voice_channel = [(GuildChannel.name, GuildChannel.id) for '(#voice channels)' in self.guild]
    db.multiexec('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO channels VALUES (?, ?, text)', (channel_name, channel_id) for chan in existing_text_channel)
    db.multiexec('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO channels VALUES (?, ?, voice)', (channel_name, channel_id) for chan in existing_voice_channel)
```

Here is my question

1. Is 'self.guild.id' on the third line is well-placed for it to fetch guild id?
2. I haven't figured out how to work with 'guildchannel' class, so, can someone show me how to do it by changing things on line 5 and 6?

As my code has custom function named 'execute', 'multiexec' and 'record', I'll show you the part of the class that I defined these functions:

```
from os.path import isfile
from sqlite3 import connect

DB_PATH = "./data/db/database.db"
BUILD_PATH = "./data/db/build.sql"

cxn = connect(DB_PATH, check_same_thread=False)
cur = cxn.cursor()

def record(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))
    return cur.fetchone()

def execute(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

def multiexec(command, valueset):
    cur.executemany(command, valueset)
```

Comment: I have several questions, what exactly is self.guild? have you defined it yourself in the class? your code is syntactically wrong in the 4th and 5th lines, are you using a string as the variable in a for loop?

Comment: @Ceres 
self.guild at Line 4 might be unnecessary, but I defined self.guild at \_\_init__ 'none', so I wanted to re-define it when I got my guild id for future uses. That's why I used self.guild at line 5

Comment: Your code will just insert None into the table then, no matter what guild the bot joins. To insert the guild id, you have to insert `guild.id` not `self.guild.id`

Comment: @Ceres Wait, I misconted lines and thought line 3 and 4 was what you were talking about. Line 5 will be changed as the answer Kai gave me below, but my intened use of 'self.guild' for re-defining \_\_init__ was at line 4

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you want the bot to store the Guild-ID, the Channel-IDs and the Channel-Names in your database.

The [on_guild_join](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_join) event has the parameter [guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild).
Guild itself has parameters like [id](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.id), [channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.channels), [voice_channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.voice_channels), [text_channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.text_channels) and so on.

So you have everything you need.

The following code example should work.

```
@Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
    db.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO war_guild (GuildID) VALUES (?)', guild.id)
    for channel in guild.text_channels:
        db.multiexec('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO channels VALUES (?, ?, text)', (channel.name, channel.id))
    for channel in guild.voice_channels:
        db.multiexec('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO channels VALUES (?, ?, voice)', (channel.name, channel.id))
```

Comment: How can I see this is working or not? invite my bot to my channel and see the changes in database?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I would do it. Run the bot, then invite it to the Discord server and see if it writes the data to the database.

Comment: Hmmm...Turns out it gets no error, but my database is empty, which was supposed to be filled.

Comment: Do you have the guilds intents enabled? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.guilds

Comment: I enabled all intents at \_\_init__ part of my bot which the code I wrote here is located (turns out I didn't need @cog.listener at here so I removed it. and the code has been fired even if I have removed it.)